# Repeater or DataList DataBind throws NullReferenceException when deleting an element

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem that is driving me nuts! I really hope that someone in here can help me solve this one...

Situation. I have a repeater with two elements showing on initial page load. Each element has a delete button, that removes that particular element from the database. When an element is deleted is should, obviously, be removed from the repeater list.

Problem. When an element is deleted I fetch the list from the database and sets the result as the data source of the repeater. Then I try to bind the data agian. If the result contains more than zero elements, then a null reference exception is thrown, and I can't figure out why (or what).
I've tried different approaches regarding when or if to DataBind and I've tried changing the Repeater to a DataList, without any luck. I've also tried setting EnableViewState to false on the Repeater/DataList.

Question. How do I update the repeater/data list when I have removed an element and why do I keep getting a null reference exception when I call DataBind the second time? The first time is when the page is loading.

```
<asp:Datalist ID="CourseInstanceDataList" OnItemCommand="CourseInstanceDataList_ItemCommand" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("Systemname") %>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="RemoveButton" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") + ";" + organisation.Id %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Datalist>
```

cs file:

```
public Organisation organisation;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        organisation = GetOrganisationFromUrl();
        BindCourseInstancesToRepeater(organisation);
    }
}

private void BindCourseInstancesToRepeater(Organisation organisation)
{
    List<CourseInstance> courseInstances = new List<CourseInstance>(OrganisationService.GetOrganisationById((int)organisation.Id).CourseInstances);

    courseInstances.Sort(delegate(CourseInstance a1, CourseInstance a2)
                                        { return a1.Name.CompareTo(a2.Name); });

    CourseInstanceDataList.DataSource = courseInstances;
    CourseInstanceDataList.DataBind();

}

protected void CourseInstanceDataList_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
    {
        // there are two arguments in this command separated by a ';'
        string[] commandArgsAccept = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ';' }); 

        CourseInstance courseInstance = CourseInstanceService.GetCourseInstanceById(Int32.Parse(commandArgsAccept[0]));
        Organisation org = OrganisationService.GetOrganisationById(Int32.Parse(commandArgsAccept[1]));

        OrganisationService.DeattachCourseInstanceFromOrganiation(courseInstance, org);

        BindCourseInstancesToRepeater(org);              
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
```

Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="App_Web_n8fdkbsv"
  StackTrace:

```
   at ASP.custommodules_elearning_admin_organisationcourseinstancelist_ascx.__DataBinding__control4(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a null reference exception because of the `organization.id` reference in your repeater markup. Initially, you are setting the value for this in `Page_Load`, but when you do a postback, you are not loading it (have an `if (!IsPostback)`).

In your item command event, you should get rid of the local variable `org`, and just use your `organization` private field instead, so that it will be set when your databinding happens.

Comment: Thanks! I was completely blinded by the Repeater, that I didn't realize that the problem was in fact elsewhere. Didn't get much help from the exception though ...